# Available Memory Space for cluster

Tags: hadoop

How can I check the size of cluster used , and available .
can I check the Ram size allocated to nodes. I don't know how to proceed, do I need to check using linux command or i can check in ambari as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the details through the UI at the Port Number (8088) like shown below

```
http://<IP of namenode>:8088/
```

And If you want to check the Details through the Command then you can check over the fsck Command. you can refer below links

1. http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2011/10/20/understanding-hdfs-quotas-and-hadoop-fs-and-fsck-tools/
2. [Hadoop commands Guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html)

   For Checking the Disk,memory Usage just open the link and Check the **Viewing the Cluster Dashboard**

[Using Ambari Dashboard](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.2.1.0/bk_Ambari_Users_Guide/content/ch_monitoring_and_managing_your_hdp_cluster_with_ambari.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Can I check the hard Disk space and RAM space on ambari.  I have checked by using command **df -h** , but I  want to see in ambari

Comment: You can refer this for the steps to check using ambari http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.2.1.0/bk_Ambari_Users_Guide/content/ch_monitoring_and_managing_your_hdp_cluster_with_ambari.html

Comment: Thanks I got it :)

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps, it's quite late to answer your question, but my answer may help others at least.
I am not sure about `Ambari` but we have cli tools to find out what you are looking for.

Before proceeding I would like to clarify couple of things.

`df -h` is a unix or linux command to check the total space and available space on a file system of that particular machine. And to check the Memory you should use the below command.

```
alexraj84@spark-m:/etc/spark/conf$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7499       4612       2886          8         70       1823
-/+ buffers/cache:       2718       4780
Swap:            0          0          0
```

But, but, that's not exactly what you are looking for. You want to know the cluster Memory availability or utilization. Use the below command to get the complete information of the cluster

```
yarn top
```

It will display some important information about the cluster memory, running applications, VCores, containers etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it on YARN Resource Manager's web page:

http://your_yarn_rm_hostname:8088/cluster/nodes

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Can I check the hard Disk space and RAM space on ambari.  I have checked by using command **df -h** , but I  want to see in ambari